# AIX show package content

Tags: package-management, aix

I have those filesets, they are not installed.

```
memdbg.adt        memdbg.msg.Ja_JP  xlC.msg.en_US      xlCcmp.13.1.2.lib    xlsmp.msg.EN_US.rte  xlsmp.msg.Zh_CN.rte
memdbg.aix53      memdbg.msg.JA_JP  xlC.msg.ja_JP      xlCcmp.13.1.2.tools  xlsmp.msg.ja_JP.rte  xlsmp.msg.ZH_CN.rte
memdbg.msg.en_US  memdbg.msg.zh_CN  xlC.msg.Ja_JP      xlsmp.aix61.rte      xlsmp.msg.Ja_JP.rte  xlsmp.rte
memdbg.msg.EN_US  memdbg.msg.ZH_CN  xlC.rte            xlsmp.msg.en_US.rte  xlsmp.msg.JA_JP.rte
memdbg.msg.ja_JP  xlC.aix61         xlccmp.13.1.2.lib  xlsmp.msg.En_US.rte  xlsmp.msg.zh_CN.rte
```

I want to know which files they contain.

On Linux I use `rpm -ql -p packagenotinstalled.rpm`, how do I do this on AIX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package files are in backup/restore format, so you can do something like:

```
restore -Tqf memdb.adt
```